# Cryptomatte from Blender to Fusion Studio 16

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am new to Blender and I am trying to export individual multi layer exr files into Fusion Studio 16 for the purpose of utilizing cryptomatte editing. I enabled the cryptomatte in the render pass properties for object, material, and asset. I then setup up a compositor node as seen in the image attached. I am using the Reactor plugin's cryptomatte. I know others have been able to do this. I just do not know what it is that they did that I am not doing. If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it. I also attached a screen shot of my Fusion Studio node build. It is what you would imagine. There is no cryptomatte file embedded anywhere in the openexr. On top of all of that, I cannot find anything on Cryptomatte for animation in Blender. I only see people using through the compositor which renders single images. I prefer single images, but it would be nice to be able to compile them and cryptomatte in Fusion through the compiled finish. [image][image]

Comment: So I think that I got it working with the file output node in the blender compositor. I am still not quite sure how to manage animation through individual files that are created by Blender and when the image file is a jpg file rather than a png file. I am sure that there is supposed to be more options that I cannot find that allow for a transparent background pass. If anyone has any tips on how to composite the animation in cryptomatte in a compiled form I would really be grateful. https://us.v-cdn.net/5021068/uploads/editor/8f/0yg9z7903ape.png

Comment: here is other image link....  https://us.v-cdn.net/5021068/uploads/editor/0w/uzv9ms81mkz1.png

Comment: You should store all render passes in a multi-layer OpenEXR (possibly with Cryptomatte passes in a separate file). This is the same for still images and animations. Yes this will produce a lot of file and require quite a bit of disk space, but jpeg is not suitable for compositing.

Answer (score 2):

### Blender

- enable Properties editor > Layers Properties > Passes > **Cryptomatte Object**
- export animation as image sequence in **Multilayed OpenEXR** format (Float Full)

### Fusion

- go to File > Import > **Footage** and select your image sequence in your directory (so it is imported as one node)
- search **Cryptomatte** (from screen i see you have it instaled, so i'm not going trhough installtation process)
- now you have to specify what object to use as mask, for that select cryptomatte node and place source cursor on desired object in image (Torus in my case) and click **Add** in properties editor, or you can type name of your blender's object directly into field (see image).

[image]

[image]

I had some issue with edge, but was solved with additional node (macro/group?) [here](https://www.steakunderwater.com/wesuckless/viewtopic.php?p=27014#p27014) (you will have to Login first). I was also asking for the same kind of node tree fix on [BA Thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/cryptomate-matte-edge-imperfection/1189344), but without help for now.

Answer (score -4):

I actually do not think that cryptomatte editing for animation is possible with a Blender and Fusion workflow, maybe Nuke. But, it was better designed for Maya that it was Blender where I believe that animation editing in a cryptomatte environment is possible.